# Error message "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Following is my controller. Method ProjectsView is to view all the listings. The second method BackendProjectSearch is for searching of projects. The first page of search result is displayed properly, but when we click on next page it gives the error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

What should I do ?

```
public function ProjectsView(){ 
$projects = projects::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(15); 
return view('backend.projects.projects_view',compact('projects')); } 

public function BackendProjectSearch(Request $request){ 
$request->validate(["search" => "required"]); 
$item = $request->search; 
$projects = Projects::where('project_name','LIKE',"%$item%")->paginate(15); 
return view('backend.projects.projects_view',compact('projects')); }
```

Following are the routes for both the methods :

```
    Route::post('/backend/project/search', [ProjectsController::class, 'BackendProjectSearch'])->name('backend.project.search');

    Route::get('/view', [ProjectsController::class, 'projectsView'])->name('projects.view');
```

View code :

```
           <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="header-navsearch">
                        <form class="form-inline mr-auto" method="post" action="{{route('backend.project.search')}}">
                            @csrf                        
                            <div class="nav-search">                               
                                <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control header-search" placeholder="Search projects…" aria-label="Search">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>                          
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Pls check route listing

Comment: please paste the route code here

Comment: Route::post('/backend/project/search', [ProjectsController::class, 'BackendProjectSearch'])->name('backend.project.search');

Comment: It is a POST as I need to REQUEST the 'search' .

Comment: Add your route and method calling code here

Comment: Please share your code where you post your data?

Comment: Yes I just added the code. Anything else I need to add ?

Comment: Please execute your command artisan `cache:clear`, `config:clear`. Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Friend , I tried that also. I saw somewhere that I need to Redirect, but cant understand how will I Redirect with COMPACT ?

Answer (score 0):

The route for this request should be `post`, not `get`.

**Example**

```
Route::post(-----);
```

Also, make sure to insert a CSRF token while making the request
it means you now cannot do something like the following.

```
<a href="{{ route('example') }}"></a>
```

Instead, you have to do something like...

```
<form action="{{ route('example') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf {{-- According to the version of laravel  --}}

     {{-- Your other codes --}}

     <button type="submit" class="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Kindly check the code I have added just now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code

```
return redirect()->route('projects.view')->with(['projects' => $projects]);
```

Your route might be little change

```
Route::get('/view/{projects?}', [ProjectsController::class, 'projectsView'])->name('projects.view');
```

and In your controller, you have to change function like this

```
public function ProjectsView($projects = null){ 
    if($projects!=null){
         return view('backend.projects.projects_view',compact('projects'));
    }
    else{
        $projects = projects::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(15); 
        return view('backend.projects.projects_view',compact('projects'));

}
```

Comment: Thanks friend. I tried this code but its not giving the desired result. It shows all the records.How can I push 'cities' also in this code ?

Comment: @Kumar `cities` is it variable? You also pass `cities` with `compact`

Comment: Sorry. But I am getting all the records , not the filtered.

Comment: @Kumar, I update my answer. Hope it solves your problem finally.

Comment: sorry friend. I am still getting all the records in the view after search.

Comment: Please `dd($projects)` in your `BackendProjectSearch` function and then `dd($projects)` in your `ProjectsView`  function. If both `dd` result same then it is confirm your output.

Comment: They both should not be the same. BackendProjectSearch should give only filtered records. Presently it is giving all the records as per your code. Maybe something wrong in the Redirect command. No idea my friend :(

Comment: @Kumar, I update my answer. When you search the project then confirm me it enters `if` condition or `else` condition in `ProjectsView`  function.

Comment: Now it ends in 404 | NOT FOUND

Comment: If you don't mind have you any `remote access` like anydesk?

Comment: Let me check. Will let u know.